# Monogame - published game doesnt start

Tags: xna, visual-studio-2013, monogame

I've wrote some simple game using monogame (on VS 2013) and bulit it with realase option. On my PC it run very well, but when i sent it to my friend its didnt start, both compiled version and one-click installer. He has computer has win 8, .NET 4.0, newest DirectX and OpenAl like mine. I have deen read older posts on stackoverfliow, but it still doesnt run.
Also when I use one-click installer on my computer, its install the game, but but after double click on icon nothing happens (no error or freez, just nothing).
How Can I correctly publish my game?
Thank you in advance for your help